# Fragment Activity crashes when onclick imageview

Tags: android, android-fragments

```
Process: sg.edu.tp.quixmovie, PID: 13707
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find method moviePoster1(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute defined on view class android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView with id 'imageView6'
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.resolveMethod(AppCompatViewInflater.java:423)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:380)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
07-19 08:53:23.900 13707-13707/sg.edu.tp.quixmovie I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 13707 SIG: 9
```

Currently I am trying to make my fragment_home onclick ImageView to my Movie1.class but it doesn't work. It keeps crashing and I can't figure out why.. Need help thank you.

**AndroidManifest.xml:**
[image: AndroidManifest.xml]

**Logcat:**
[image: Logcat]

**Home.Java:**
[image: Home.Java]

Comment: Please post code into the actual question instead of screenshots of the code...
Take a look at [mcve] and [ask].

Comment: Post complete logcat in text format

Comment: The screenshots of the code you posted does not match with that logcat. Please paste complete code from your Movie1.java, Home.java and the logcat output so the problem can be understood completely

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach...

```
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
  ImageView iv = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView6);
  iv.setOnClickListener(this);
  return view;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one,

```
public class Home extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
        ImageView iv = view.findViewById(R.id.iv_click);
        iv.setOnClickListener(this);
        return view;

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        if (v.getId() == R.id.tv_click) {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "dssas", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in your `XML` file containing `imageView6` do you have `android:onClick` attribute set to the ImageView? If yes then remove that line and use `setOnClickListener` as mentioned in other answers

If you want to use `android:onClick` do the following:

**In XML**

```
<ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView6"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:onClick="moviePoster1"/>
```

**In HomeActivity**

```
public void moviePoster1(View view) {
//do your action
 }
```